# Alternative standards to IPA

Tags: discussion, ipa

Are there any alternative standards to the IPA for phonetic transcription *without* the use of special characters? For instance, in [this chart](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/FAA_Phonetic_and_Morse_Chart2.svg) of ICAO phonetic alphabet, phonetic pronunciations are listed without the use of any special characters.

Is there a standard for mapping IPA to such phonetic equivalents?

Comment: This is really more of a linguistics question than an EL&U.SE question. You might consider committing to the [Linguistics.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics) site.

Comment: @Robusto I guess so. However, this can be useful for English language learners as this could fall under 'Problems encountered by people learning English' in the FAQ for EL&U.SE. Perhaps this could be moved to meta EL&U?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various respelling alphabets used in many dictionaries.  Each works differently and should be looked up in the source using it -- there's no standardization.

There are transcription schemes for IPA that don't use special characters -- SAMPA and its extension X-SAMPA.

You don't want Americanist phonetics which is rapidly falling out of favor and does use special characters.

Answer (score 2):

Someone asked this already some time ago. But like I said there, IPA is the way to go.

Charles here touched some important matter: **Standardization**. I'll treat this differently.

You can use "any means" to explain, let's say, the pronunciation to a broad audience, but who will understand what? There are some things that can be understood,  but there will always be slight differences and, not to be underestimated, **mistakes**.

Take for example, the word "*book*" and "*cool*". If I had to explain their pronunciation to some foreigner, how should I with a spelled out pronunciation? Although it may seem so, that "oo" in book is different from the "oo" in cool.

IPA for "*book*" is **|bʊk|**, "*cool*" is **|kuːl|**. This is because of some reasons I won't explain here (too long and off topic) but the important point I wanted to show is that, although they seem similar words, they have different pronunciations, which is hard and not efficient to be shown with something other than [IPA](http://www.translationdirectory.com/images_articles/wikipedia/IPA_chart_2005.png).

Comment: I did read the recent question regarding IPA use on meta; in fact, that's what made me ask this question. Which is why I was wondering whether there's a standardised way of mapping from IPA to one without a special char symbol set. @Charles pointed out something like what I was thinking of, for instance.